# To which group is 6:101 addressing?

Tags: quran, tafseer, allah

> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a son when He does not have a companion and He created all things? And He is, of all things, Knowing.

Quran 6:101

Which group is this ayah aimed at?
This group seems to belive that believes that **needs** a consort to have a son.

Does this ayah mean that **if** Allah decided to have a son, he could only have a son through biological means like humans?

Comment: It means he has no equal, so having a son goes against that essential notion of God

Answer (score 1):

In his tafsīr of the verse you are asking about:

> بَدِيعُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ ۖ أَنَّىٰ يَكُونُ لَهُ وَلَدٌ وَلَمْ تَكُن لَّهُ صَاحِبَةٌ ۖ وَخَلَقَ كُلَّ شَيْءٍ ۖ وَهُوَ بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ عَلِيمٌ
>
> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a son when He does not have a companion and He created all things? And He is, of all things, Knowing.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-An'am 6:101](https://quran.com/6/101)</sub>

[Ibn Kathīr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kathir) quoted Al-'Awfy saying that:

> وَخَرَقُوا لَهُ بَنِينَ وَبَنَاتٍ بِغَيْرِ عِلْمٍ
>
> For they have attributed to Him sons and daughters without knowledge.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-An'am 6:100](https://quran.com/6/100)</sub>

This is not talking about any specific group as such. There are several groups that had a notion of Allah having sons, daughters, or both, e.g., Egyptian [Horus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horus), Indian [Krishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna), Indian [Mitra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitra), Persian [Mithra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithra), Mexican [Quetzalcoatl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatl), Syrian [Tammuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammuz_(mythology)), etc. All such groups have similar notions of a savior son of God.

The word *walad* in Arabic is better translated as offspring as it has the same root origin as to give birth. This is a form of ridicule by irony. Ibn Kathīr explains that to have an offspring, it means there would be an equal to Allah, let that be the offspring, or a wife through which the offspring is obtained, or any other of His creations, and Allah has no equal and no match. The irony is: If Allah does not need a consort to have a son, why would He need a son in the first place as a sacrifice as is the case in the stories above? Needless to say, this is not limited only to Horus, Krishna, etc., but to any other similar notion.

Comment: So Allah sent a prophet in western Arabia to adress religious issues happening across the world?

Comment: @aska123 why not if Allah says:"And We have not sent you, [O Muhammad], except as a mercy to the worlds." (21:107) http://legacy.quran.com/21/107 and "Blessed is He who sent down the Criterion upon His Servant that he may be to the worlds a warner -" (25:1) http://legacy.quran.com/25/1  and many more